# Evaluating a Straight in Visual Basic

Tags: arrays, vb.net, poker

Okay so I've been trying to debug this for hours and today and last night.  I need to create a simple array(3,12) and use it to evaluate a 5 card poker hand.  The problem is that it never returns a "TRUE" Boolean for anything above a 4 of a kind, And `CheckStraight()` and `CheckFlush()` are the two functions I call before 4 of a kind so I think the problem lies there, however its possible its in my array, however I've spent hours on the array checking every angle and I think at this point I've ruled it out as a problem.    I think the problem lies in my `CheckStraight()` function.  I see no logical reason for it to not work.  Oddly when I run it (I created a text-box to output the sum of the calculation in the function) it always comes out at 1, when it should be 5.  Here's my `CheckStraight()` Function:

```vb
Private Function CheckStraight(ByVal varHand) As Boolean
    Dim varValue As Boolean = False
    Dim varAces As Integer
    Dim varKings As Integer
    Dim varQueens As Integer
    Dim varJacks As Integer
    Dim varTens As Integer

    varAces = varHand(0, 0) + varHand(1, 0) + varHand(2, 0) + varHand(3, 0)
    If varAces > 1 Then
        varAces = 1
    End If

    varKings = varHand(0, 12) + varHand(1, 12) + varHand(2, 12) + varHand(3, 12)
    If varKings > 1 Then
        varKings = 1
    End If

    varQueens = varHand(0, 11) + varHand(1, 11) + varHand(2, 11) + varHand(3, 11)
    If varQueens > 1 Then
        varQueens = 1
    End If

    varJacks = varHand(0, 10) + varHand(1, 10) + varHand(2, 10) + varHand(3, 10)
    If varJacks > 1 Then
        varJacks = 1
    End If

    varTens = varHand(0, 9) + varHand(1, 9) + varHand(2, 9) + varHand(3, 9)
    If varTens > 1 Then
        varTens = 1
    End If

    '***txtDebug.Text = varAces + varKings + varQueens + varJacks + varTens***
    If varAces + varKings + varQueens + varJacks + varTens = 5 Then
        varValue = True
        Return varValue
    Else

        Dim varCount As Integer = 0
        Dim varTotal As Integer = 0
        Dim varX As Integer = 0
        Dim varY As Integer = 0
        Do While varY < 13
            varTotal = 0
            varX = 0
            Do While varX < 4
                varTotal = varTotal + varHand(varX, varY)
                varX += 1
            Loop
            If varTotal > 1 Then
                Exit Do
            ElseIf varTotal = 1 Then
                varCount += 1
                If varCount = 5 Then
                    varValue = True
                    Exit Do
                End If
            ElseIf varTotal = 0 Then
                varCount = 0
            End If
            varY += 1
        Loop
        If varCount = 5 Then
            Return varValue
        Else
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

The debug line should be bolded and italic.  I'd really appreciate any input and if you need more code just ask.

Comment: Its generally easy to detect a straight - you arent using Option Strict so it is hard to tell what some of those things are.  Put the cards in order, then compare to a series starting with the lowest card: `testSeq = Enumerable.Range(sortedValue(0), 5)` that creates a straight sequence, so `IsStraight = (testSeq.Except(sortedValue).Any() = False)`.  You generally have to do it twice to allow for an Ace low straight (Wheel). you also need to do it in a loop for games with more than 5 card hands

Comment: thanks for the tip ill try to figure out how to use that

Comment: What value(s) are stored in the array to represent when a card is present?